# Progress bars in Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have a javascript method, that I Call in the HTML for the progress bar.
I need to do something like that:[Progress00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qhwq.jpg)

With the CSS code I have this:[Actual_Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzwun.png)

The javascript code work corretly and depend of seven steps like Progress00

```
<script>
$(function(){
// Initialisation des champs
$('#dateJour').val(convertDateToString(new Date()));

});
  var eta= "<?php echo  $etat;?>";
  var minDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_dte;?>"));
  var today = new Date();
  var maxDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_fin;?>"));
  // Mise à jour de l'avancement
    var pourcentage = 0;
  if(eta=="1- Dosssier recu sans DTE"){
    pourcentage = 0;
  }
  else if(eta=="2- Dossier avec DTE recu"){
    pourcentage = 16.6666667;
  }
   else if(eta=="3- Dossier avec RIP nomme"){
    pourcentage = 33.3333333;
  }
  else if(eta=="4- En cours de preparation par le RIP"){
    pourcentage = 50;
  }
  else if (eta=="5- Dossier prepare"){
  pourcentage = 66.6666667;
  }
  else if (eta=="6- En attente de realisation"){
  pourcentage = 83.3333334;
  }
  else if (eta=="7- Dossier realise"){
  pourcentage = 100;
  }


  $("#avancement").reportprogress(pourcentage);
 </script>
```

CSS:

```
/* Barres de progression */
#avancement
{
border : 1px solid #d3d3d3;
width : 100;
height : 20px;
position : relative;
color : black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Couleur de la barre */
#avancement div.progress
{
position : absolute;
height : 100%;
overflow : hidden;
background-color : GoldenRod;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Texte sur la barre */
#avancement div.progress .text
{
position : relative;
text-align : center;
color : white;
margin-top : 2px;
}

/* Texte sous la barre */
#avancement div.text
{
position : absolute;
text-align : center;
margin-top : 2px;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}
```

And HTML:
     `<div id="avancement" ></div>`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to do something like Progress00 in the picture. I need help with the CSS.

Comment: A simple search could have helped you find what you're looking for. Check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz)

Comment: Thanks. The link was useful.